# select from the result of execute(@query)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using this SQL query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Animal2) 
                    from animals
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Animal1, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select animal1, animal2, Corelation
                from animals
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(Corelation)
                for animal2 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b713/6)

When I execute the query I get a table as a return.

How can I select from that table? I tried to use `SELECT * FROM (*past here the script*)` but it did not work. I just need to use the result of the execute(@query) as a table and select from it (to put it in a new table). How can I do it?

Thanks

NOTE: that query was an answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125187/sql-query-to-select-records-in-a-specific-format-using-pivot-or-other/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `into` and a global temporary table - then you don't have to define the table columns in advance.

```
set @query = 'SELECT Animal1, ' + @cols + 
    +' into ##temp '
    +' from 
             (
                select animal1, animal2, Corelation
                from animals
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(Corelation)
                for animal2 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

select * from ##temp
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Insert into ... exec` format, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp1 (
   [Animal1] varchar(5), 
   [Cat] decimal(10, 5), 
   [Dog] decimal(10, 5), 
   [Mouse] decimal(10, 5)
)

Insert Into #Tmp1
 execute(@query)  

select * from #tmp1
  where cat = 1
```

Of course, since the column names are dynamic, you'll need to shift the create statement to dynamic sql too.

[SQL Fiddle with the fixed version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b713/13)

[SQL Fiddle with the dynamic version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b713/42)